# ASP.NET add onclick to div via code behind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm using ASP.NET and I want to be able to click on a `<div>` and set the background to a color (prefably an image later on). This `<div>` is generated by code:

```
public void generate (int[] _blocks, int _width, int _height, int _distance) {
        int HorizontalBlocks = _blocks[0];
        int VerticalBlocks = _blocks[1];
        int top = 0;
        int left = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < VerticalBlocks; i++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < HorizontalBlocks; x++) {
                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl Div = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");

                Div.ID = "Box_" + x + "_" + i;
                Div.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, _width.ToString() + "px");
                Div.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Height, _height.ToString() + "px");
                Div.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Top, top.ToString() + "px");
                Div.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Left, left.ToString() + "px");
                Div.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "#848484");
                Div.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Position, "absolute");
                Div.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Cursor, "pointer");
                Div.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                Div.Attributes.Add("onclick", "setBackground();");

                grid.Controls.Add(Div);

                left += _width + _distance;
            }

            left = 0;
            top += _height + _distance;
        }
    }
```

I have tried creating the method `setBackground();` but I can't seem to figure out how to set the background of the currently clicked `<div>`.

Comment: setBackground() is a javascript or a C# method ?

Comment: @renefc3 Doesn't matter, tried both. Preferably C#.

Comment: if you using javascript add a return false;

              Div.Attributes.Add("onclick", "setBackground();return false;");

Comment: setBackground() will be a method you will need to declare in you javascript.

Comment: @KieranQuinn How should I get the ID of the `div` I clicked and set it the background of that ID. Only worked with C# so far.

Answer (score 0):

The `Panel` Control is a Control which wraps it's contents inside a `<div>`. And you can change it's properties from code behind.

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">

    <%-- html content here --%>

</asp:Panel>
```

Code behind.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel1.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

And if you want to change background colors you can do this for example.

```
<style>
    .myDiv {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        background: inherit;
    }
</style>

<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"><div class="myDiv"></div></asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"><div class="myDiv"></div></asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"><div class="myDiv"></div></asp:LinkButton>
```

And the click event in code behind.

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton linkButton = sender as LinkButton;
    linkButton.BackColor = Color.Green;
}
```

Comment: Every div has it's own ID.

Comment: You can add an id to the div's

Comment: The problem is, there is no limit to the amount of divs. Depends on the screen resolution how much is being generated on the x and y axes. And the users preference.

Comment: If you want access to the properties of all those div's with C#, you need to create Controls dynamically, add them to a PlaceHolder, keep track of the totals created with a ViewState or Session and also rebuild them on every PostBack. You're doing somethins similar already, but instead of HtmlGenericControl you use other Controls that can also handle a click to do a PostBack.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working faster than I thought. This is what I did.

I used this:

```
                Div.Attributes.Add("onclick", "div_click(this.id)");
```

And then I use this via script:

```
        <script>
            function div_click(clicked_id) {
                alert(clicked_id);
            }
        </script>
```

Thanks for all the replies